# Applying pivot_wider to dataframes within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, pivot-table, lapply

I have created a list of dataframes with split like so:

`dataframes_list <- split(df, f = df$variable3)`

Each dataframe (131 in total) there is in long format and have the same variables and structure. I want to perform the function pivot_wider in all of them simultaneously.

I have been struggling with some functions of the apply family, but could not get it done:

1. First I reduced the number of variables within each dataframe selecting only those that should be used for pivoting

   `dataframes_list_2 <- lapply(dataframes_list, function (x) select(x, variable1, variable2))`
2. Then I tried pivot_wider

   `dataframes_list_3 <- lapply(dataframes_list_2, function(x) pivot_wider(x, names_from = variable1, values_from = variable 2)`

What I obtain in this way is the list with dataframes that contain 1 observation per variable, each of them being a vector of (in this case) 12 values. What I want instead is this:

[image: Level1 Level2 v1,1 v2,1 v1,2 v2,2 v1,3 v2,3]

Because there was a warning telling me that my observations were not uniquely identified, I varied the code above including such variable. But what I got was this:

[image]

Can someone give me some answer to this issue?

Thank you

Each dataframe in the list has this aspect:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some sample data? You can use `head(dput(data))` and copy/paste the output in your post.

Comment: The format is now available in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way:

```
df_list <- lapply(1:length(my_list), 
function(x) (pivot_wider(my_list[[x]], names_from = names, values_from = values)))

bind_rows(df_list)
```

You will get what you needed! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
map(my_list, ~ (pivot_wider(.x, names_from=1,values_from= 2)))
```

number 1 and 2 are the columns in my tibbles. You can use `map_dfr`. To combine the data sets you can use `unnest` of `bind_rows`.